# LogicApps - Set DateTime nullable field to 'null'

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Within Logic Apps trying to set a Dynamics 365 field to 'null', which effectively clears out the DateTime offset. (see attached image)

Code View looks like the following:

...
"body" : {
    "delayuntil" : null
}
...

Logic Apps designer, tries to set the field as follows:

...
"body" : {
    "delayuntil" : "null"
}
...

But, this is incorrect, as I need it to be null

Help?

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?  Is the designer changing it from null to "null" or is it not working in D365?

Comment: "body" : { "delayuntil" : null } is the only correct way to set it to null. "null" will give you a date time parsing error, since yo are passing a string object with value "null" to Dynamics365 instead of a null-object. Same question as @Johns-305, what is the exact issue or what is your question?